# Able to cast to nodes not on my network

Tags: windows-10, networking

I just so happen to hover over Cast to Device on my Win10 PC and noticed two nodes that are not on my network. I have my home network pretty locked down with only using static IPs, MAC filtering, over 20 character complex password to join my network, WPA2, and get a notification when new nodes connect to my network.

I have verified every node on my network and these two devices are not on my LAN.

But why can I cast to them? When I click the listed nodes, it asks me for a WPS pin. So I assume I would be able to connect if I had the PIN.

That's not normal, right? What gives?

[image: Picture of the two nodes not on my network]

Answer (score 7):

Looking at the device names, at least the first entry is using "[Wi-Fi Direct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Direct)", which works by having the device (printer) serve *its own* Wi-Fi network for direct connections rather than going through the existing network infrastructure. (It's similar to Apple's AirDrop.)

Devices offering Wi-Fi Direct are discovered in the same way as regular nearby Wi-Fi access points, although they (probably) carry certain additional information in their SSID beacons indicating their purpose.

(I don't know how Fire TV Sticks work, but I suspect they might be using Miracast, which is also built around the same Wi-Fi Direct.)

---

If someone targetting your Wi-Fi network manages to discover the WPA2 passphrase, your other defenses won't help you much – MAC filtering becomes trivial to bypass (just borrow the MAC address of another known-good device), static IP addresses even more so. They don't participate much in locking things down; it's more or less just theatre.